# send_keys(Keys.RETURN) is throwing an error

Tags: python, selenium

I'm new to Selenium(Python).
I'm trying to get the program to open google.com and type in a piece of text to be searched.
Everything is fine, except it doesn't click Enter to search.

Here's the source code

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Anaconda3\Lib\idlelib\chromedriver.exe')

driver.set_page_load_timeout("10")
driver.get("http://google.com")
driver.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys(//The piece of text)
driver.find_element_by_name("btnK").send_key(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(4)
```

And it is throwing me this error
`AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'send_key'`

Can anyone tell me where I'm wrong and what I should do to fix it?

Comment: Can you 1) send the text with a `\n` or use an additional `.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)` so it looks like you at the end pressed enter in the query box or 2) `.click()` the button element?

Comment: I didn't get you

Comment: I just typed `/n` at the end of the text and it worked. Thanks Mate!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to press enter key then follow below solution.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\chromedriver.exe")


driver.set_page_load_timeout("10")
driver.get("http://google.com")
element=driver.find_element_by_name("q")
element.send_keys("selenium")
# element=driver.find_element_by_name("btnK")
element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN);
```